# Opening the IE browser 11 in Kiosk mode via batch file, stalls the rest of my code until the browser page is gone

Tags: bash, batch-file, command-line

The following code opens the google.com webpage in kiosk mode and then waits 5 seconds before performing more commands.

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -k "https://www.google.com"
timeout 5
Extra code....
```

When I open this is regular browser mode, the countdown begins immediately in the console before continuing with the extra code. But in kiosk mode the code stops running. I must close the browser and wait a few seconds before the timeout countdown begins and the rest of the code continues.

Why is this happening, and how can I get around it and continue the code while the browser is open in kiosk mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kiosk mode seems to be blocking.

To fix this, start the process in background like this:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -k "https://www.google.com"
timeout 5
```